# How do you declare functions with predefined arguments?

Tags: c++

I want to know how do u declare a function with definite arguments. It's said to be good practice to put the function declaration at the beginning , before the main() function and then its definition, but in this case the compiler gives me an error, becase it's like if it doesn't see the formal arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void function(int i=1, char a='A', float val=45.7);

int main()
{
  function();
  return 0;
}

void function(int i = 1, char a='A', float val=45.7)
{
  cout << "i: " << i << endl;
  cout << "a: " << a << endl;
  cout << "val: " << val << endl;
}
```

I tried to insert the formal arguments in the declaration, but  it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the way to initialise the function args to default values.
You dont need to pass default args in defination. They should be given only in the declaration itself.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void function(int i=1, char a='A', float val=45.7);

int main()
{
  function();
  return 0;
}

void function(int i, char a, float val)
{
  cout << "i: " << i << endl;
  cout << "a: " << a << endl;
  cout << "val: " << val << endl;
}
```

Now, this code will work like a charm.
Link to working example -> http://cpp.sh/4j7lx

Answer (score 2):

You can put predefined arguments either in the forward declaration *or* in the function parameter, but ***not*** *both*

If your function has a forward declaration, you *really should* only have predefined arguments in the *forward declaration*, ***not*** in the function parameter.

Change that to:

```cpp
void function(int i, char a, float val)
{ 
     // you shouldn't use using namespace std;
     std::cout << "i: " << i << '\n'; // notice the use of newline character instead of std::endl
     std::cout << "a: " << a << '\n';
     std::cout << "val: " << val << '\n';
}
```